# Is there some kind of a ChildrenChangedEvent on panels?

Tags: .net, wpf

I'd like to do something with every control inside a `Panel`.

I created a boolean attached property for `Panel`s. Since attached properties have a `PropertyChangedCallback`, I can react on this attached property being set to true in XAML (or later on in code or by binding).

But how do I detect that the content of the `Children` collection of the panel has changed? I couldn't find a ContentChanged oder ChildrenChanged event in panels and the `UIElementCollection` (type of the `Children` property) doesn't seem to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can inherit and override OnVisualChildrenChanged.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visual.onvisualchildrenchanged?view=netframework-4.8